# Simple vector bundle isomorphic to one of its twistings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a vector bundle over an algebraic curve $C$, ad assume that that $V \cong V \otimes L$ for some line bundle $L$.

If $V$ is decomposable this is clearly possible, for example take $V \cong \mathcal{O}_C \oplus L$ with $L^2 \cong \mathcal{O}_C$.

> **Q.** Does $V \cong V \otimes L$ imply $L \cong \mathcal{O}_C$ if  $V$ is simple?

Comment: If $L$ has a non-trivial section $s$, then don't we have a map $V \otimes \mathcal{O}_{C} \to V \otimes L$ induced by $Id \otimes s$, which is not multiplication by a constant?  By your assumption, this would give an endomorphism of $V$ which is not simply multiplication by a constant.  This contradicts simplicity.  Since either $L$ or $L^{-1}$ has sections, I think this suffices.  Is there a hole in this argument?

Comment: @Benighted: if $V\cong V\otimes L$, $L$ is torsion, so it has no global sections unless it is trivial.

Comment: Let $L$ be a 2-torsion line bundle on $C$, and $\pi :\tilde{C}\rightarrow C $ the associated étale 2-sheeted covering. Let $V=\pi _*M$  for any line bundle $M$ on $\tilde{C} $. Then $V\otimes L\cong V$; if $M$ is not the pull back of a line bundle $M$ on $C$, it is easy to see that $V$ is simple.

Comment: Thanks for a nice counterexample. It saved me from wasting time for wrong line of argument.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is *no*, as shown by the following classical example due to Atiyah.

Take an elliptic curve $E$, choose a point $p \in E$ and consider the unique non-split extension $$0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_E \longrightarrow V_p \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_E(p) \longrightarrow 0.$$
Then $V_p \simeq V_p \otimes L$ for every $2$-torsion line bundle $L$ on $E$, see Remark p. 35 of **[F]**.

Note that $V_p$ is stable and thus simple, see **[F]**, Theorem 9 p. 89.

**References.**

**[F]** R. Friedman: *Algebraic surfaces and holomorphic vector bundles*, Springer 1998.

Comment: Thanks for nice and detailed information.